# Change the label text, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Here, is my code snippet:

```
def message(name, button):
    button['state'] = DISABLED
    mgs_label = ttk.Label(root)

   if button["text"] == "Encryption":

       mgs_label.pack_forget()
       mgs = encryption(name)
       mgs_label = ttk.Label(root, text=mgs).pack(side=LEFT)

   if button["text"] == "Decryption":

      mgs_label.pack_forget()
      mgs = decryption(name)
      mgs_label = ttk.Label(root, text=mgs).pack(side=LEFT)
```

When i am click the button whether it is encryption button or decryption button it is comes at mentioned position.
Here is the snapshot :
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COz1A.png)

And When i am click the another button the text comes after the previous one, i want to remove the previous text and then the last mgs should be displayed.

second snapshot : [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOEn4.png)

Even i tried to make global variables but then the problem is encryption or decryption is done but the mgs is not showing on the GUI here is the code for that :

```
encryption_label = ttk.Label(root)
decryption_label = ttk.Label(root)
def message(name, button):
    button['state'] = DISABLED
    global encryption_label, decryption_label
    if button["text"] == "Encryption":

       if decryption_label.winfo_exists():
          decryption_label.pack_forget()

       mgs = encryption(name)
       encryption_label["text"] = mgs
       encryption_label.pack(side=LEFT)

    if button["text"] == "Decryption":

       if encryption_label.winfo_exists():
          encryption_label.pack_forget()

    mgs = decryption(name)
    decryption_label["text"] = mgs
    decryption_label.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: try to use different label variables for ```Encryption``` and ```Decryption``` states

Comment: @crackanddie I tried and accordingly edit the question but still not working.

Comment: @HimanshuGurjar second approach is better but your indent seems off. Since in the second approach, you are using two labels there is no need to set the text every time message is called instead set text in the declaration itself `encryption_label = ttk.Label(root, text='Successfull encrypted')` similarly for the decryption. But a better way to go for it would be to declare a single global instance of the label and update the text.

Comment: your first approach will not work because you are creating a new instance of  the label each time you are calling the message so using `mgs_label.pack_forget()` will never hide the previous label. Also , In  `mgs_label = ttk.Label(root, text=mgs).pack(side=LEFT)`  `msg_label` is `None` as `pack` returns `None`

Comment: @JacksonPro Yes, now i get the point thanks for the advice. But even using the single global label variable it is not working so, I just made a label at caller function and pass it as argument to the called function and then just configure it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating the label only once and use label.configure to change the text.
You should provide a working example instead of a code snippet.  I made one for you.
Thank you for your question.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def e():
    message(None,x_button)
def d():
    message(None,y_button)
def message(name, button):
    #button['state'] = tk.DISABLED

    if button["text"] == "Encryption":
        mgs_label.configure(text = 'encrypted stuff')

    if button["text"] == "Decryption":
        mgs_label.configure(text = 'decrypted stuff')
  
root = tk.Tk()
x_button = tk.Button(root,text = 'Encryption',
                     command = e)
y_button = tk.Button(root,text = 'Decryption',
                    command = d )
mgs_label = ttk.Label(root)
y_button.pack()
x_button.pack()    
mgs_label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```